# Mysterious Blank Space While Using "display:table/table-cell"

Tags: html, css, web

Attempting to figure out why the blank space is appearing between the image and the menu.

The associated html and css are as follows:

```
    <header class="header_nav">

        <img src="img/logo.png" class="logo"/>

        <nav class="nav_bar">
            <ul>
                <li>Home</li>
                <li>The Nest</li>
                <li>Our Sparrows</li>
                <li>Volunteer</li>
                <li>Support</li>
                <li>Contact</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

    </header>



body, html
{
width:100%;
min-height:100%;
margin:0;
border:0;
padding:0;
background-color: #F0EEE8;
}

.header_line
{
margin:0;
border:0;
padding:0;
position:absolute;
top:0;
height:20px;
width:100%;
background:#75B0A8;
border-bottom:5px solid white;
}

.header_nav
{
display:table;
margin:0;
border:0;
padding:0;
margin-right:10%;
margin-left:10%;
width:80%;
margin-top:35px;
height:83px;
}

.logo
{
display:table-cell;
margin:0;
border:0;
padding:0;
}

.nav_bar
{
display:table-cell;
margin:0;
border:0;
padding:0;
vertical-align:middle;
}

.nav_bar ul
{
margin:0;
border:0;
padding:0;
list-style:none;
}

.nav_bar ul li
{
margin:0;
border:0;
padding:0;
display:inline;
font-family:Georgia,serif;
font-size:20px;
}
```

No matter what I try I can't get it to fix. Also, my thought is that this has to do with the fact that I used `display:table` and `display:table-cell` but if it is "unfixable" while using that trick then my issue is that I need some other way of getting `vertical-align:middle` to apply to the menu bar.

Thanks

Comment: Is the space between the logo and the menu. Not the white border? Right?

Comment: I wish you could have been more clear

Comment: @user3317140 The question clearly reads _"blank space is appearing **between the image and the menu**"_.

Comment: @polley1994 You could leave them on `display: inline-block` and set the exact height of the menu putting `position: relative` and `top: 50px`.

Comment: @bcrash The issue was the space between the logo and the menu, not the white border, correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's your new CSS.

The problem was with .logo, .header-nav and nav-bar.

If you tell an element to display as a table cell, that element behave as though it is a table cell. Unfortunately, the unique positioning powers of tables means it is very easy to make mistakes that will cause your layout to break.

Instead, familiarise yourself with using inline-block on block elements sitting on the same row.

```
body, html {
    width:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    margin:0;
    border:0;
    padding:0;
    background-color: #F0EEE8;
}

.header_line {
    margin:0;
    border:0;
    padding:0;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    height:20px;
    width:100%;
    background:#75B0A8;
    border-bottom:5px solid white;
}

.header_nav {
    display:block;
    margin:0;
    border:0;
    padding:0;
    margin-right:10%;
    margin-left:10%;
    width:80%;
    margin-top:35px;
    height:83px;
}

.logo {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin:0;
    border:0;
    padding:0;
}

.nav_bar {
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0;
    border:0;
    padding:0;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

.nav_bar ul {
    margin:0;
    border:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
}

.nav_bar ul li {
    margin:0;
    border:0;
    padding:0;
    display:inline;
    font-family:Georgia,serif;
    font-size:20px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll have to read through the CSS and clarify why your edits work, but for the sake of responding in a timely fashion I just plugged it in to see, and it both achieved my goal and got rid of the need for elements to pretend to be tables.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `display:table-cell` on `.logo` and `.nav-bar` use `display:inline-block` on both an add `vertical-align:middle` to `.logo`.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/KMbBh/)**

Comment: This is pretty much what ended up working, yes. Along with adding `display:block` to `.header_nav`.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion, use wrappers to locate your elements and give them the proportions you need so that you can move them at will. And do not use table-cell display, not in this case anyway.

```
.left-col{width:25%; float:left}
.right-col{width:75%; float:right;}
```

Here is a fiddle with your fix [***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/ZNst7/)

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in this property `.header_nav{width:80%}`
to center the header you could use this properties instead:

```
.header_nav{
width:100%;
display:block;
margin:auto;
}
```

and to fix the navigation bar margin use

```
.nav_bar{
    margin-top:2%;
    }
```